# Best way to include the stripe.js script in every gatsby page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, gatsby

The [gatsby-stripe-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-stripe) is deprecated. It states that stripe.js has its own solutions now on how to load stripe into the code, e.g. `const stripe = await loadStripe(secret);`

But stripe states in its [readme](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#ensuring-stripejs-is-available-everywhere) that you should add the stripe script to every file/page and not only at the checkout page in order to check for fraud.

What would be the best way to do so. I am quite new to gatsby, is it a valid solution to just add the stripe script to the index.html in the public folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now `npm install @stripe/stripe-js` and then `import '@stripe/stripe-js';` in every page and that will [include it as suggested](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#ensuring-stripejs-is-available-everywhere).

Comment: ok, I wasnt sure if this would be the correct way or if there is a nicer solution. Thank you very much for your reply!